# Strongloop custom script does not exit

Tags: javascript, node.js, strongloop

I'm probably overseeing something very basic, but I have this basic strongloop custom script which is suppose to do some data cleanup.

The scripts runs fine, this is not the problem, does all it is suppose to do (all console.log are printed) but the process never exits.

Is there something I have to do to end strongloop?

```
var app = require('../server/server');

app.models.product.find({}, (err, result) => {
    console.log('result', result);
    //Do data cleanup
    console.log('done now');
});
```

Comment: It never exits or it doesn't exit at the end of the file ?

Comment: Sorry, the bottom console.log made it confusing. It ever exited, I've found the solution to my problem and posted it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok seems a connection to the mysql server was kept open.
If I manually disconnect the process exits nice and tidy.

```
var app = require('../server/server');

app.models.product.find({}, (err, result) => {
    console.log('result', result);
    //Do data cleanup

    //Disconnect datasource
    app.dataSources.mysqldb.disconnect();
    console.log('done now');
});

console.log('end of file');
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of gotcha that belongs on Stackoverflow! Don't forget to accept your own answer ;-)